# How to disable csrf in Spring using application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

The following property exists:

`security.enable-csrf=false`

BUT csrf protection is still on if I add the property to `application.properties`.

What works is to disable it programatically.

But I'd prefer properties configuration. Why could it not be working?

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Comment: That will only work if Spring Boot is allowed to configure security, if you are messing around with Security yourself, that property won't do anything. Also make sure you are on a version of Spring Boot that supports that property.

Comment: I'm on newest `-1.5.4` and I only added the `configure()` method to disable the csrf. If I remove that method completely, the property is still not taken into account. The only custom security config is with `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` that I use to set `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. But that should not impact the csrf.

Comment: That depends, if you have `@EnableWebMvc` on it that will disable auto configuration.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is my only annotation. And I'm extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? As that isn't really clear from your question...

Comment: Yes, added spring-boot to tags.

Comment: Did you enable basic authentication (which is the default) or did you disable that... Also the default is to disable csrf protection so you must have some additional security configuration (properties or classes) that disables the default setup.

Comment: I have `security.basic.enabled=true` and using maven `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. There is too little information too help you. imho you have something in the code that disables the default configuration (could be something you have or additional dependencies) however with the little information in the question that is hard to tell.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` uses an imperative approach you can inject the value of the `security.enable-csrf` variable and disable CSRF  when it be false. You are right, I think this should work out of the box.

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${security.enable-csrf}")
    private boolean csrfEnabled;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       super.configure(http);

       if(!csrfEnabled)
       {
         http.csrf().disable();
       }
    }
}
```

What I did was to set that variable to false in my application.yml for when I had a *dev* spring profile active, although you could create a profile called *nosecurity* for such purposes too. It eases this process a lot:

--- application.yml ---

```
# Production configuration
server:
  port: ${server.web.port}
admin.email: ${admin.email}
#etc
---
spring:
  profiles: dev

security.enable-csrf: false

#other Development configurations
```

I hope it suits your needs

### Update on Dec 17th of 2017

Based on a [comment of a Spring Boot member](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11170#issuecomment-350805732) this issue is fixed on new versions of Spring: I had it on version `1.5.2.RELEASE` but it seems that in version [1.5.9.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.9.RELEASE) (the latest stable one to the date before version 2) its already fixed and by default **csrf** is disabled and it can be enabled with `security.enable_csrf: true`. Therefore a possible solution could be just upgrading to version `1.5.9.RELEASE`, before making a major one to version 2 where the architecture might be quite more different.

### Update on Jun 02nd of 2023

The method `http.csrf` requires now a customizer of type `Customizer<CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>` to configure csrf.
Therefore, instead of:

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

you should use

```
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. Though it still not explains why the crsf configuration is not entirely disabled by just setting the configuration property.

Comment: An issue should be raised in their Spring github and/or jira

Comment: In the [Spring Security documenation for CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) it says that by default its on and to disable it you must do it by Java or xml code. The `.properties` attribute is something that should be implemented by [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html): An issue opened in [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11170)

Comment: CSRF is enabled by default as of Spring Security 4.0. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure

Comment: Suppose I kept it "disable" via external configuration & I am running my app. Now at some point of time I want to "enable"  CSRF so I changed property to TRUE and hit the /refresh end point, but does that mean that Spring container will again call "configure" method of "AuthConfig" ? If not then I need to either re-stage my app or restart my app so new configuration is loaded by spring container.

Answer (score 7):

For Spring Boot 3.1.0 (spring-boot-starter-web) use the code snippet below

```
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
```

For Spring Boot 3.1.0 (spring-boot-starter-webflux) use the code snippet below

```
http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable);
```

Answer (score 6):

**An update:**

Looks like there is an issue with disabling CSRF using application.properties on spring-boot 1.x (and thanks to Eliux for openning this [case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11170)).

So my solution for **spring-boot 1.5.7** with an embedded tomcat is disabling CSRF via **SecurityConfig** class (note that this way I keep the tomcat ootb basic authentication):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Note: 
        // Use this to enable the tomcat basic authentication (tomcat popup rather than spring login page)
        // Note that the CSRf token is disabled for all requests (change it as you wish...)
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Add here any custom code you need in order to get the credentials from the user...  
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("myUserName")
            .password("myPassword")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that for versions like 1.5.9 or superior this is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

For Spring Boot 3. It helped me:

```
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess:
spring-security 6.1.4

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // ...
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/*")
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Or

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // ...
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

See: [*Disable CSRF Protection*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#disable-csrf)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to disable it with the following line in the spring-security.xml file:

<security:csrf disabled="true"/>