# Enable CSRF and Avoid 403 Error for Springboot Microservice without any Browser based clients

Tags: spring, security, microservices, csrf

When we do csrf.disable() -CSRF is disabled and helps to avoid 403 error. but when we remove it we get 403 error. I understand CSRF is enabled by default but if I dont add csrf.disable() it throws 403 error for POST call

I checked some references and understand generating unique CSRF tokens/Some level of Filtering implementation before the calls can help here but I am not getting references how to implement it. can any one share code snippet for the configurations towards this.

Can we say CSRF attacks are not applicable for Microservices without any direct  Browser based clients.

Comment: Reference: https://community.pivotal.io/s/question/0D50e000054WrewCAC/how-to-enable-and-use-csrf-in-spring-boot-security

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable csrf in Spring using application.properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824382/how-to-disable-csrf-in-spring-using-application-properties)